# Proof of the derivate of the normal vector of curves

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

i need a proof for the derivate of the normal vecture of curves.

$n'(s)= -kt - \tau b $ ,

where k is the curvature, t is the speed vektor and $\tau$ is the torsion, and $n'(s)$ is the derivate of the normal vecture, and b the binormal vector.

i saw proofs yet, but they arent such detailed as i could understand. could please someone give me a detailed proof for that formula?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no detailed proof. This is in every differential geometry textbook. Indeed, you cannot prove it, as this equation is the definition of $\tau$ (or of $-\tau$, depending on which book you use). What you need to check is that $n'\cdot n = 0$ (why?) and that $n'\cdot t = -t'\cdot n = k$ (by definition).

Comment: I might add that it looks like you're using DoCarmo's book (based on the sign of the torsion). You might find my differential geometry text (freely available at the link in my profile) more helpful.

Comment: @TedShifrin i think n' * n =0, because they are orthogonal? but i dont know why i have to know that. and k is by my definition t'/n? i have no idea how to get that formula thats why i ask

Comment: Read the first page of section 2 of chapter 1 of my notes. This is all explained carefully. Also, break the habit of writing a vector divided by a vector; that makes no sense.